# EqualsVerifier Assertion Error: Significant fields: equals does not use <fieldName>, or it is stateless

Tags: equalsverifier

The setup, java 8 using lombok, meanbean and equalsverifier(huge fan of all 3, and also limited in what versions I can use per co. policy - on 2.3.3 of equalsverifier):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class A {...}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class B extends class A {...}
```

I get the Significant fields error calling EqualsVerifier:

```
EqualsVerifier.forClass(B.class)
                .withRedefinedSuperclass()
                .suppress(Warning.STRICT_INHERITANCE, Warning.NONFINAL_FIELDS, Warning.INHERITED_DIRECTLY_FROM_OBJECT).verify();
```

Changed class B as follows, and got redefined superclass error instead:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper=false)
class B extends class A {...}
```

Changed class B again as follows, and got significant fields error instead:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper=false)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
class B extends class A {...}
```

Any suggestions? I don't know how to get passed this one.

Answer (score 1):

Creator of EqualsVerifier here.

I don't quite have enough information to be able to help you -- what fields doe `A` and `B` have? Also, I'm not sure if Lombok's `@Data` can be inherited; you'll have to check their documentation or run some experiments.

That said, combining `equals` with inheritance correctly is hard to get right. The advice I usually give people is, don't do it. If you have to, I've written something about it in the [EqualsVerifier manual](http://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/inheritance/). I'd also recommend reading [this article](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) for some background info.

As general rules of thumb:

- Always call super in your `equals` methods if you override them and intend to add state.
- Make your classes `final` if you don't need to extend from them. In this case, `B` could be final, which would make it easier for you to appease EqualsVerifier.
- If you don't know what code Lombok generates, use [Delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok).

Comment: I have a field named `createdDate` and is not a part of equals method, is there anyway I can use `EqualsVerifier` in this case, I am getting similar error.

Comment: Sure: use `withIgnoredFields`. See https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/ignoring-fields/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lombok annotation in child class has resolved this issue.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
```